# configure freeimage in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, freeimage

I doing a school project  and need to create a 2D polygon in OPENGL then use it as texture so  want to use the freeimage library.

But the problem is that i do not know how to configure and add the freeimage library to my Xcode project.

Answer (score 1):

goto http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html download and install all of the libraries for the formats that you want to support (png,jpg,etc), pick a nice path for everything... perhaps /usr/local then start installing things ... most libraries use a very similar build/install routine

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make all
sudo make install
```

something like that should work for everything, then you will need to add the library to the linker section of your target and include the headers in your source files and all should be well.

Comment: thanks try to do that but its giving me a lot of errors like unknow symbol for architure X86 im coding in mac os x lion

Comment: Post specifics please... If you are missing symbols it probably means your headers are in the default search path but the libraries aren't.

Comment: And then what library should I link? The one in /usr/local or /usr/local/lib/libpng.a ?

Comment: if the library is in "/usr/local/lib/libpng.a" i think you can pass the little L flag like -l"/usr/local/lib/libpng.a"